# How do I mock a ResourceBundle using Spring and PowerMock?

Tags: spring, junit, mocking, powermock

I'm using PowerMock 1.5.1 and Spring 3.1.1.RELEASE trying to mock a ResourceBundle.  I have tried

```
    ResourceBundle resourceBundleMock = createMock(ResourceBundle.class);
    expect(resourceBundleMock.getString("error.invalid.login")).andReturn(errorMsg);
```

but am getting the exception below

```
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find resource for bundle $java.util.ResourceBundle$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$8b09d230, key error.invalid.login
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getObject(ResourceBundle.java:374)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getString(ResourceBundle.java:334)
    at org.mainco.subco.ebook.test.mvc.LoginControllerTest.testLoginError(LoginControllerTest.java:578)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:66)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:310)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:86)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:94)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:294)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:127)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:282)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:84)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:207)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:146)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:118)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:101)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

How do I mock what is returned by a call to the resourceBundle.getString method for use in my Spring controller?  I instantiate a ResourceBundle in Spring by using

```
 private static ResourceBundle resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("UserMessages", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Comment: Try `expect(resourceBundleMock.getString("error.invalid.login", Locale.ENGLISH))...`

Comment: This results in a compilation error, "The method getString(String) in the type ResourceBundle is not applicable for the arguments (String, Locale)"

Comment: It's the same code that you posted in your question (last line). How can one of them compile and the other not?

Comment: The code I posted only has one String argument to "resourceBundle.getString" whereas the one you suggested has two arguments.

Comment: You posted this code: `ResourceBundle.getBundle("UserMessages", Locale.ENGLISH);`. Please read your question again and check it for mistakes.

Comment: You're referring to the static field which initializes itself using "getBundle".  I'm trying to mock a call to the method ResourceBundle.getString (notice getBundle vs. getString) after the class has been initialized.  The getBundle method takes two arguments, but the getString method takes only one.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

K, figured it out -- wasn't injecting my mock properly.  The following healed the pain

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ SecurityContextHolder.class })
public class LoginControllerTest 
{

    @Mock
    private ResourceBundle bundle;

    …

    @Test
    public final void testLoginError()
    {
        mockStatic(ResourceBundle.class);
        expect(ResourceBundle.getBundle("UserMessages", Locale.ENGLISH)).andReturn(bundle);

        final String errorMsg = "Invalid Login. Please reenter your username and password.";
        expect(bundle.getString("error.invalid.login")).andReturn(errorMsg);

        expect(loginService.getUrlProperties("localhost")).andReturn(url);
        replayAll();
```

Comment: +1 You need to mock both the `getBundle()` and the `getString()` calls.